# Using the result of an XPATH in another xpath expression

Tags: xml, xpath, jaxp

I have a XML like the below. Here I wanted to slect the attribute value of node **b** which is 23 take that value and go down the xml and pick the node **j** of node **f** which has the id value 23. Can this be achieved in a single xpath expression.

I am using JAXP for xml processing

```
<a>
  <b id="23"/>
  <c></c>
  <d></d>
  <e>
    <f id="23">
       <i>123</i>
       <j>234</j>
    <f>
    <f id="24">
       <i>345</i>
       <j>456</j>
    <f>
    <f id="25">
       <i>678</i>
       <j>567</j>
    <f>
  </e>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
//f[ @id = //b[1]/@id ]/j
```

Comment: I have one more question. What is the xpath to return a value based on the xpath,  This is to say if //b[@id=23] then return 'profit' else 'loss'.

Comment: The above question I asked was answered in a seperate thread.